# PHP block in HTML code

Tags: php, html, marquee

am trying to use a php function within my html code but it keeps treating this block as a comment!(colored green in the source and not outputting anything)  though i used the same function in another file and it worked just fine even within html...

```
function x (){
$x = 'hello';

echo('<marquee direction="left" scrollamount="3" behavior="scroll" style="width:300px;

height: 15px; font-size: 11px;">');

echo $x;

echo'</marquee>';

}


<?php

echo x();

?>
```

The html file am using is a template i found online...any suggestions for what i should be checking?
Thanks!

Comment: The `<marquee>` tag has been deprecated.

Comment: The `<marquee>` tag ranks right up there with `<blink>` on the "Kill it with fire and then nuke it from orbit" annoyance scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what will make that work:

```
<?php

function x (){
$x = 'hello';

echo('<marquee direction="left" scrollamount="3" behavior="scroll" style="width:300px;

height: 15px; font-size: 11px;">');

echo $x;

echo'</marquee>';

}



x(); // Not echo, because the function doesn't return a value.

?>
```

Here's a slightly nicer version:

```
<?php

function x ($message){

$html = '<marquee direction="left" scrollamount="3" behavior="scroll" style="width:300px; height: 15px; font-size: 11px;">'.$message.'</marquee>';

return $html;

}



echo x('hello');

?>
```

Comment: thank u :) but the previous code was working just fine in a separate file..but when i write it in the file am working on it keeps ignoring the block or just executing half of it ..this is the output when i wrote ur code  :  
'.$message.''; return $html; } echo x('hello'); ?>

Comment: Sounds like your file has an error earlier on. Can you post the full content of the file? Perhaps on somewhere like pastebin.com (unless you want to edit your question – syntax highlighting etc isn't good in comments!)

Answer (score 2):

Coupe of things about the code you pasted:

1. `function x ()` must also be inside `<?php` and `?>` tags to be treated as php code.
2. Your function x() is **NOT returning** anything so you need to call it as `x();` and not as `echo x();`

Answer (score 0):

The function itself needs to be wrapper in the  tags

Comment: no i just copied it here like this! they're included in my code

Comment: Wrapped* and yes inside the <?php ?> tags, Meaning... You have to put your php function inside the area you marked as being php

Comment: The easiest way to understand what Gnostus is saying is that the <?php bit needs to be right at the start of the function, so the whole thing is between <?php and ?>.

Comment: i understand! its included in the main code! i just forgot to write it here!